# How to stop showing target URL in ReverseProxy in Golang using NewSingleHostReverseProxy()?

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

I am trying to have a reverse proxy in Golang, but I am unable to stop target ip from showing in browser ie. it is simply redirecting to wikipedia (target) rather than showing doing reverseproxy.
Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "net/url"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    target := "https://www.wikipedia.org"
    remote, err := url.Parse(target)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(remote)
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/forward/{rest:.*}", handler(remote, proxy))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func handler(ur *url.URL, p *httputil.ReverseProxy) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.URL.Host = ur.Host
        r.URL.Scheme = ur.Scheme
        r.Host = ur.Host
        r.URL.Path = mux.Vars(r)["rest"]
        p.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code with gofmt for better readability.

Comment: Thanks I hope it is readable now

Comment: If the proxied page sents a redirect - then the browser will redirect. Try `curl  https://en.wikipedia.org/ -D /dev/tty` which shows a redirect to `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`. You could add a handler to inspect responses and rewrite headers to match your proxy, but that's a non-trivial amount of work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want to use it as a micro service so I want to keep header shown to client as the proxy server URL rather than the resource URL.